# Why do you need let keyword in do block?

Tags: haskell, let

What is the reason for having `let` in `do` block.

```
-- codeblock A
main = do
  let a = 0
  let f a = a + 1
  let b = f 0
  print (a,b)

-- codeblock B
main = do
  a = 0
  f a = a + 1
  b = f 0
  print (a,b)
```

Assume all `let` without `in` must followed by `=` (Is this true?)

Compiler should be able to imply `let` from `=` and preprocess/de-sugar `codeblock B` to `codeblock A`

using `let` in this case seem to be unnecessary, like you could write `codeblock C` but choose to write `codeblock D`

```
-- codeblock C
main = do
  print (a,b)

a = 0
f a = a + 1
b = f 0

-- codeblock D
main = do
  print (a,b)

function  a = 0
function  f a = a + 1
function  b = f 0
```

To clarify the my assumption doesn't not include `let` that followed by `in` which should leave untouched.

```
-- codeblock E
main = do
  a = 0
  f a = a + 1
  b = f 0
  c = let d = 1 
          e = 1
      in d + e
  print (a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know why it was done, but here is one reason I can imagine: it allows you to specify which bindings should be established sequentially, and which simultaneously, which can matter in the case of shadowing.

For example, imagine that your suggestion is implemented, and then consider:

```
foo :: [Int]
foo = do
  x <- return [1]
  y = 0:x
  x = [1..5]
  y
```

There are two reasonable ways to desugar this:

```
foo1 :: [Int]
foo1 = do
  x <- return [1]
  let y = 0:x
  let x = [1..5]
  y

foo2 :: [Int]
foo2 = do
  x <- return [1]
  let y = 0:x
      x = [1..5]
  y
```

`foo1` evaluates to `[0,1]`, and `foo2` to `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`. This is a strange way to write your code, surely, but the fact that the `let` is required to be explicit means there is no ambiguity as to what you intend.

As noted in the comments by [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647332/why-do-you-need-let-keyword-in-do-block/40648442#comment68536873_40648442), shadowing is not the only reason you might need to be explicit about how your `let` bindings are grouped: a function definition might require multiple equations, to match multiple parameter patterns.

Comment: I want to add that it is not only about shadowing. Using `let` you can define local functions in `do`-block. While w/o `let` syntax for local functions may become ugly.

Comment: Related: a function definition may span over multiple equations. Compare: `do ... ; let { f (K1 x) = ... ; f (K2 x) = ... } ; ...` vs `do ... ; let f (K1 x) = ... ; let f (K2 x) = ... ; ...` (shadowing)

Answer (score 5):

One argument in favor of the `let` is that it stands out more in `do` blocks that may otherwise be filled with a variety of monadic assignment-like operators (think something filled with the [operators defined in `lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html)).

```
do
  p1.x += delta             -- (+=) is a custom operator
  p2.y -= delta             -- (-=) is a custom operator
  let delta' = delta*delta
  p3 .= Point delta' delta' -- (.=) is a custom operator
```

Here I can easily distinguish the syntactic sugar for abstracting `delta'` from actual monadic code because of the `let`.

Comment: Can you override operator `(=)` ? If no, you would know that `delta'` is a `let` binding (less distinguishable , but still can).  If yes, you just answer my question.

Comment: @wizzup, no, you cannot override `=`. It's not an operator at all, but rather primitive syntax. I think the point is that there are operators that look similar enough to confuse.